# can someone explain the application of row.weights and sampling.weights in lavaan?

Tags: r, causality, structural-equation-modeling, propensity-scores, lavaan

I am trying to include the weight derived from Inverse Probability of Treatment Weighting (IPTW) into a structural equation model (SEM). However, it is unclear how it should be incorporated into the model and how `lavaan`'s `sem()` function will compute the outcome.